# How to Use Cache Memory concept in objective-c

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, web-services, caching

//  Web service request

```
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: urlLoc]];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestData length]];
        [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody: requestData];

        NSError *respError = nil;
        NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request returningResponse: nil error: &respError ];

  //returndata is response of webservice
 NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];


        NSDictionary *results = [responseString JSONValue] ;
        NSLog(@"chat data- %@",results);

        NSString *strResults = [results objectForKey:@"d"];
        NSLog(@"result string is-%@",strResults);
```

this is the code that I am using for my Data fetching from web service. But i have  to do this every time when come to this page.
Is that any method that can store my data in Cache memory so i need not to request every time.

I Am using

NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

but i dont know how to use - (NSCachedURLResponse *) connection this method
thanks...

Comment: Ex: **[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:60];**

Answer (score 1):

You need to use cache as of your needs according to this [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLRequest/requestWithURL%3acachePolicy%3atimeoutInterval%3a): whenever you requesting a `NSMutableURLRequest`...

For Ex:

```
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData timeoutInterval:60];
```

For More details Kindly look into the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLRequest/requestWithURL%3acachePolicy%3atimeoutInterval%3a)